# What is the handle of a gift bag called in everyday conversations?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

**What is the handle of a gift bag called in everyday conversations?**

For example,

"**The strap/strip/string of the gift bag**"

Comment: I don't know that I've ever had a conversation about one :-), but I'd call it the handle or cord. A strap is always flat.

Comment: @KateBunting, "**the bag with a blue cord**" or "**the blue cord on the bag**" are idiomatic. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it is the means of carrying the bag, I'd just call it a 'handle'.

Comment: I think most people would just call it a [***drawstring**,*](https://definedictionarymeaning.com/topic/148341/drawstring) even though *usually* a drawstring goes all the way around the top edge of the (fabric, not thick paper) bag so it can be pulled tight.